# ffmpeg can take picture preview but errors on streaming video?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

Im trying to setup a Homebridge on a raspberry pi so I can have a cheap home camera.
I was able to get everything set up alright but when trying to edit the config for the homebridge-camera-ffmpeg plugin I keep getting errors.

Im able to take a picture preview with the camera just fine but video seems to throw errors.

```
[Logitech-C525] [fatal] Invalid input file index: 1.
[Logitech-C525] FFmpeg exited with code: 1 and signal: null (Error)
[Logitech-C525] Error occurred terminating main FFmpeg process: Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
```

here's my config

```
{
            "platform": "Camera-ffmpeg",
            "cameras": [
                {
                    "name": "Logitech-C525",
                    "videoConfig": {
                        "source": "-s 1280x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0",
                        "stillImageSource": "-s 1280x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0",
                        "maxStreams": 2,
                        "maxWidth": 1280,
                        "maxHeight": 720,
                        "maxFPS": 30,
                        "audio": false,
                        "debug": true,
                        "packetSize": 188,
                        "mapvideo": "1",
                        "mapaudio": "0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Does using ffmpeg directly work? `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -t 10 output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan it gives the same error of `FFmpeg exited with code: 1 and signal: null (Error)`

Comment: Show output of `ls /dev/video*`

Comment: @llogan `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video10  /dev/video11  /dev/video12  /dev/video13  /dev/video14  /dev/video15  /dev/video16`

Comment: That does not look like an error code from ffmpeg itself. I'm guessing you're still trying it via a script, wrapper, or whatever this homebridge-camera-ffmpeg. I was assuming you would run ffmpeg directly as asked.

Comment: @llogan ah sorry I was on autopilot! I ran it as just the command and it does work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

changing the `source` to be `-re -r 6 -s 1280x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0` and deleting the `maxFPS` as well seemed to work!